# What is the best way to add double input field form type in Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I would like to create double input field form.
A feature name and a feature value.

What is the best approach to do it in on product form?

I am using Symfony 2 and MySQL Entity.

I would like to achiev something like this.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Create a FeatureType which includes the required fields then use the CollectionType: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: @mark.sagikazar You should submit that as an answer because it is _the_ way to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a FeatureType which includes the required fields then use the builtin CollectionType: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html